# add numbers together in python, numbers are extracted from a list of dict

Tags: python, syntax

New to python! Here is the list of dictionaries I have in python:

```
[{'amt': 400, 'name': 'whatever1'}, {'amt': 300, 'name': 'whatever3'}, {'amt': 500, 'name': 'whatever2'}]
```

I would like to add all the 'amt' together without using a complete for loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Do you imagine it would be more efficient? Do you want to make it look more cryptic than the obvious way?

Comment: So new to 'pyton' that you can't spell it yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sum(L['amt'] for L in list_of_dicts)
```

should do it.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it without a for loop, but perhaps a generator doesn't count as a "complete for loop".

Comment: @sammiwei it sounds like you have something like this in your code `sum = 0`.  Don't do that.  `sum` is a keyword, and you've overridden it with an int value.

Comment: probably they re-assigned the name `sum` to a number before trying your code.. there was another answer here with `sum = 0` in it

Comment: @jgritty yep, that's exactly what I did!! Thanks!

Comment: @mhawke That is why python recommends not to use lowercase L in PEP 8. I will change it for clarity.

Comment: @jgritty `sum` isn't a keyword, but a built-in function.  You're still correct that he shouldn't overwrite the names he wants to use.

Comment: +1 This is the most 'Pythonic' answer... I just added mine as a beginner's alternate

Comment: Thanks, @jamylak - in retrospect, l is of course a bad choice. I didn't think that through before just selecting the first letter of the variable name :)

Comment: @Darthfett you're technically correct, the best kind of correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import imap
sum(imap(itemgetter('amt'), your_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
>>> LofD=[{'amt': 400, 'name': 'whatever1'}, {'amt': 300, 'name': 'whatever3'}, {'amt': 500, 'name': 'whatever2'}]
>>> SumofAmt=0
>>> for each in LofD:
...    SumofAmt+=each['amt']
... 
>>> SumofAmt
1200
```

Comment: Doesn't quite fit the 'without using a complete for loop' part of the question.